# Understanding Assembly Layers in .NET Framework vs .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I'm trying to understand the assembly process in both .NET Framework and .NET Core so I can see what the differences are, but I've been struggling to find relevant information specifically about .NET Core. From my research, I've gathered that in .NET Framework, compilers translate code into MSIL/CIL code, which is then translated into native code by the Common Language Runtime (CLR).

Extracted from wikipedia - creating runnable software in Microsoft's .NET framework:

[image: image of extract]

However, this seems to be specific to the .NET Framework and therefore only applicable to Windows, which contradicts the portability goals of .NET Core.

I'm seeking clarification on the assembly process in .NET Core and how it differs from .NET Framework. Are there significant differences in how code is compiled and executed? Additionally, where can I find detailed information about the various layers of assembly in both frameworks?

I've Found CoreCLR as an alternative to CLR, but I'm uncertain if the other layers remain the same or if some might disappear in .NET Core due to being unnecessary. For instance, could certain layers be omitted in .NET Core?

Any insights or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: _"However, this seems to be specific to the .NET Framework and therefore only applicable to Windows, which contradicts the portability goals of .NET Core."_ - No. There's nothing Windows-specific about it - it's how Java works too, for example. Microsoft has supported .NET (in various forms) on non-Windows, non x86 devices [going right back to 2002](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_Personal_Objects_Technology).

Comment: _"about the various layers of assembly in both frameworks?"_ - There are no "layers of assembly". That's just not a thing.

Comment: _"I've Found CoreCLR as an alternative to CLR, but I'm uncertain if the other layers remain the same or if some might disappear in .NET Core due to being unnecessary. For instance, could certain layers be omitted in .NET Core?"_ - You seem to have some major misconceptions about what .NET even is...

Comment: The fundamentals are the same between .net framework and .net core. But .Net core have expanded the ways applications can be [published and deployed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/), like Ahead Of Time compilation or Self contained deployment.

Comment: @Dai Sorry for my explanation, as layers i was refering to the different stages or steps that the compiler goes through during the assembly process.

Comment: @Yisus fundamentally there's very little difference in the build process. MSIL is still used in both. It's the runtimes and the implementation of the base class library (BCL) that are very different. The runtime is always operating system specific. Framework only worked on Windows. Core (i.e. .NET5+) is cross-platform. The assemblies themselves are actually compatible between Framework and Core but it's the dependencies that differ. If you target .NET Standard though the assemblies are even interchangeable. Maybe there's something more specific you're looking for?

Comment: BTW CoreCLR is the runtime so it's not really part of the compiler/linking process.  They don't even call it CoreCLR anymore, I don't think. It's just the runtime. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime

Comment: @EmperorEto I wouldn't go so far as to say they're "very different" - I consider .NET Framework 4.x and .NET 5+ to basically be like cousins - except one of them is younger, prettier, smarter, faster, etc

Comment: @dai sure I just mean that they rewrote big chunks of the BCL for Core and the runtimes - correct me if I'm wrong - were also a gutjob from Framework. But of course you're right that's almost all blackbox stuff. From the dev's perspective they're extremely similar.

Comment: It's hardly a blackbox: most of the .NET Framework sources are on `referencesource.microsoft.com` - and .NET Core+ is fully open, so we can compare the two and see where they just lifted huge chunks of BCL code from one into the other.

Comment: Ok now you're just nitpicking, so count me out. Peace and love.